# Symfony page protected by simple password

Tags: php, symfony, password-protection

I want to **protect a page with a password**, I know how to do it in legagy PHP but I want to do it with best practices of Symfony, with the use of a component, firewall or something like this.

I specify this is not a user authentication, but just an access to any visitor who enters the correct password

All good advice will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hello, have a glance to http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache you could make use of simple http-basic-auth
add a `.htaccess` file to your /web folder in symfony root

make sure it has these lines

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "UNDER CONSTRUCTION" 
AuthUserFile  /absolute/path/to/.htpasswd 
require valid-user
```

you can generate the .htpasswd file for example here : 
http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: yes I know that too but this is not my question => "I want to do it with best practices of Symfony"

Comment: got that, you can also let symfony do this for you, check out http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#basic-example-http-authentication